# Model.find() not finding in Mongoose with RailwayJS

Tags: mongoose, railway.js

I'm having real trouble using find in my test railwayjs app. In my model:

```
data is => "email":"test","password":"[FILTERED]"
```

**Model**

```
User.login = function(data){
    var user = new User;
    user.email = data.email;
    console.log('user email is => ' + user.email);
    user.password = data.password;
    User.find({email: user.email}, function(err, user){
        console.log(user);
    });
}
```

**Output**

```
user email is => test
null
```

Where test is in my database (mongoose running as mongod).

*I really cant figure out why its coming up null..*

I use user.save() elsewhere and it saves to the database fine.

I am a total rookie, so it could be something obvious, any help / pointers is massively appreciated.

*edit*

To add to this:

```
User.all(function (err, users) {
        console.log(users);
        render({
            users: users
        })
    });
```

works perfectly...

Comment: try logging the error message

Comment: err = [Error: Invalid ObjectId]

Comment: I'm currently having this problem too. I've tried everything I can think of. I'm starting to think that it's a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reported this as a bug on the Google Group.

Edit: It turns out that you must now do this:

```
User.all({ where: { email: user.email } }, function(err, user){
```

The documentation is available at [JugglingDB Github](https://github.com/1602/jugglingdb). It should be updated in the RailwayJS website too.

Comment: Link for anyone interested: http://groups.google.com/group/railwayjs/browse_thread/thread/a88aad1eaba3265